# How to host multiple hidden services with XAMPP or Apache?

Tags: onion-services, vidalia, server

Ok, so my operating system is Windows 8, Vidalia Tor Browser Bundle Control, and XAMPP server.

I have done the following steps with no success at getting more than one service running, and many times my efforts to my one working service going down as well. Here' what I've done so far...

1. I changed the doc root in Apache's httpd.conf file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`. Similar to this

   `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject1"`
2. Went to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` and told Apache to listen to multiple ports, replace that with below content

   101. Listen 80
   102. Listen 8001
   103. Listen 8002
   104. Listen 8003
3. I added the following files to my `C://xampp/htdocs` folder: myproject1, store, store1, store2, store3, and store4. I also saved different colored basic HTML templates to each folder saved as "index.html" so they'd all have a different home page if I got it too work by any chance.
4. Then  I opened "Settings" in Vidalia and then clicked the "Services" tab and added six services, in which I made target for each 127.0.0.1, for "Port" I defined the following #1-80, #2-8000, #3-8001, #4-8002, #5-8003, and #6-8004, and I created six new folders in my "C://Users/Me" directory [[#1-"myproject1", #2-"store", #3-"store1", #4-"store2", #5-"store3", and #6-"store4"]] in which I defined "Directory Path" of each service.

   These are the services I created in Vidalia settings w/ domains:

   #1|wjjk36dllny3ghdn.onion|Port: 80|Path: C://Users/Me/myproject1

   #2|am2nx7kbu2drhtdr.onion|Port: 8000|Path: C://Users/Me/store

   #3|toxk66hmbjwuwkva.onion|Port: 8001|Path: C://Users/Me/store1

   #4|q74aww7ypl6gaok3.onion|Port: 8002|Path: C://Users/Me/store2

   #5|aps56zfyup2pwxl5.onion|Port: 8003|Path: C://Users/Me/store3

   #6|dqt25doh3u5nutor.onion|Port: 8004|Path: C://Users/Me/store4

   [#1-6 Target: 127.0.0.1]
5. Then went to “C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf”, and added to following to the bottom and saved it.

   ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/store1"
   ServerName localhost:8000

   ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/store1"
   ServerName localhost:8001

   ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/store2"
   ServerName localhost:8002

   ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/store3"
   ServerName localhost:8003

   ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/store4"
   ServerName localhost:8004

---

Please tell me whatever i am missing (in english please i'm not stupid i'm just young and still have a ton to learn). If your instructions get to me where I can host the 6 services from my server and know where the location of each service's root so that way I can begin coding my sites then please also leave a bitcoin address if you want coffee. Been trying to figure this out for a century so I owe ya more than coffee..

Comment: Vidalia is now out of service. You should either use the Tor Browser Bundle or Tor as service for Windows.